# Question Titles that are not Questions but Titles

Tags: discussion, editing

Should question titles be actual questions or can they be titles? I've been going through a bunch of old questions, and it seems there are quite a few questions with titles that aren't question but titles.

Ex. My question title.  It's a title, but isn't a question.

Basically, my question is which is preferred? Question titles that are questions or question titles that are merely titles in disguise?

Comment: They should be questions. There was an MSO post or blog about it, IIRC.

Comment: I think problem statements should be fine.  Sticking "How can I fix this?" on the end just to turn it into a question seems pointless to me.

Comment: It's perfectly fine for them to be titles.  In particular there are a lot of questions that don't easily distill to a one-line question, and so the topic of the question is better for the title.

Comment: Isn't this title a title and not a question?

Comment: I stated that in my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Question titles don't *have* to be questions. *Do* try to phrase them as questions, but *don't* edit existing questions just for that reason.

There was a statistical study that found that questions with an actual question as a title were more likely to get answered / got more views, so for high-profile questions we do sometimes make that edit - but that's not a strict guideline we need to enforce for all questions.

Comment: I tend to edit them into question format if it's currently unclear or filled with superfluous stuff, like *"Can't spongle my blork in Blork Run 2... PLEASE HELP!!11!ONE!"*  Would become *"How do I spongle my Blork?"*

Comment: I think editing questions that are already on the front page just to change the title is fine.  I would say don't edit old posts just for that reason.

Comment: Now I really want to get my hands on a copy of *Blork Run 2*....

Comment: @Beofett it's available as a package deal with *BattleToads: 9001* at your local GameStop.